# Fitting a power law model with an additional linear term

Tags: regression, python, fitting, curve-fitting, power-law

A model of the form $y=a\cdot x^b$ can be linearly fitted by taking logs on both sides - giving $\ln(y)=\ln(a)+b\cdot\ln(x)$, where $\ln(y)$ is regressed against $\ln(x)$. This is a standard textbook approach.

What if there was an additive linear term included - e.g. $y=a\cdot x_1^b + c\cdot x_2$, how would you fit this for $a$, $b$, and $c$? Taking logs doesn't seem to do the trick, what other alternative methods are there?

Comment: "*A model of the form $y=a⋅x^b$ can be linearly fitted by taking logs on both sides*" ... such an argument only works when $y$ is strictly positive, and the transformation of the model without regard for what happens to the error term generally only works when the errors are very small.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for something like nonlinear least squares, e.g., `nls` in `R`. Here is a snippet.

```
nl.eq <- function(x1, x2, a, b, d) {
  (a*x1^b+d*x2)
}

n <- 10000
x1 <- runif(n)
x2 <- rnorm(n)
a <- 2
b <- 3
d <- 4
y <- a*x1^b + d*x2 + rnorm(n)

nlsreg <- nls(y ~ nl.eq(x1, x2, a, b, d), start = list(a = 1, b = 1, d = 1))
summary(nlsreg)
```

Comment: You mean a real-world example (my code already has a numerical example)? Many variables exhibit polynomial relationships, see e.g. wage returns to experience which may not increase linearly but flatten off for experienced employees.